# Present simple vs. present perfect

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, present-tense

I'm doing a key word transformation and I've come to this sentence:

> There aren't any eggs left.
>   "We ***_*__*_*** eggs".

I should complete the sentence with 2–5 words using the word "run".

At first I thought of

> We run out of eggs.

but could I use present simple here if it's not a repeated event? Should I use

> We've run out of eggs.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Writing advice is on topic at Writers.SE. There is also a new site in development for English language learners. Please support it: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=oPlZO9tQY4g8GxFV_g6lKw2 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pretty much as you've been arguing:

> We run out of eggs.

Running out of eggs is a thing that we do.

> We've run out of eggs.

We have recently run out of eggs, and therefore it can reasonably be inferred that we have no eggs.

Comment: Also, if "using the word 'run'" means you can use it in any form, there are more alternatives such as "We *ran* out of eggs."

Comment: True that, @MετάEd